# Poor performance with KO on a larger data grid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a decent sized data-grid (basically an interactive table) around 600 rows.

I noticed that binding KO to this grid actually takes substantial amount of time, esp. during the databind. On older browser the situation is even worse, the processor is peaked for almost a minute.

The biggest chunk of performance block seems to be coming from the line that performs the databind, NOTE: This is the initial databind, so many of reply to handling large update does not seem to be applicable.

Also mapping plugin was used to convert json objects into viewmodels on the fly. However the line that performs the mapping itself did not seem to take up too much time compared to the line that databinds.

Unfortunately paging is out of the question due to the requirement. Is there any general tips/pointers on optimizing larger view models and KO?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could offer a json data-dump and the part of html/js that binds the json. I would be glad to help with a jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and posted in the Knockout Google group.  Michael Best recommended [trying some custom bindings](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/6fnCDG0hs68).

Since you're doing edits, his knockout-table binding won't work for you.  But you might try the [knockout-repeat](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding.  It's supposed to be faster than Knockout's native foreach (at the cost of some additional complexity in your HTML).  The final option is to create your own binding that builds your grid all in one go.  In theory, building the entire grid in memory and stuffing it into the DOM complete will be faster than modifying the DOM in discrete bits.

KoGrid is probably not what you want, but there are probably some hints and tips embedded in the source.

Answer (score 0):

One advice when using the mapping plugin is to only map the properties that you need. Mapping all properties to observables in large data sets can be a real performance killer.

Comment: The line that does the mapping seems ok, but the databind is really slow. Unless the databind is affecting the databind also. This is also the initial databind.

Comment: It's when you applybindings to your viewModel that knockout must do the heaviest work. The mapped data must now render html for all your loops and track changes for all your observables from the view. If you simplify your loop to only use a simple unordered list and only output 1 property I am sure your binding appear faster. It would be easier to help if you posted a jsfiddle.